# How do i add a parent constructor to a child constructor with parameters. I have tried the parent::__construct but still has an error

Tags: php, inheritance

//here is the parent class code and constructor
//I know that I should use the parent::__construct() method but it is still coming up with an error. How //do i set the car class to have the manufacturer class variables.

```
class Manufacturer {

    public $tradingAsName;
    public $baseName;
    public $country;


    function __construct($tradingAsName,$baseName,$country){

        $this->tradingAsName =$tradingAsName;
        $this->baseName=$baseName;
        $this->country=$country;

    }

class car extends Manufacturer{

    public $carName;
    public $yearMade;    


    function __construct($carName,$yearMade){
        parent::__construct();
        $this ->title = $carName;
        $this->yearMade=$yearMade;



    }
```

Comment: Your parent constructor is expecting three parameters but you are passing exactly zero. That won't work and the error message should be telling you as much.

Comment: From an OO perspective, is a car really a kind of manufacturer?  Also the car isn't passed enough information to even call the manufacturer constructor.

Comment: Thanks you. how do I go about it. I want to add a field to the car that gets the manufacturers data such as the the tradingAsName and the country.

Comment: Instead of extending Manufacturer Class your class should have Manufacturer type variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments to OP, a `car` is definitely not a type of `manufacturer`. It would be better to add an already-instantiated `manufacturer` object into your `car`, as follows:

```
class Car {
    public $manufacturer;

    function __construct($carName,$yearMade, $manufacturer){
        $this->manufacturer = $manufacturer;
    }
}   

$man = new Manufacturer($tradingAsName,$baseName,$country);
$car = new Car($carName,$yearMade, $manufacturer);
```

And then you would access manufacturer details like this:

```
$carMadeIn = $car->manufacturer->country;
```

Here, we're using [composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), as one should when associating related but functionally divergent objects. (You might end up dealing with car and computer manufacturers, etc.) Now, to illustrate a more proper use of "extends", one might for example have:

```
class ElectricCar extends Car {
    public $batteryAmps;

    public function __construct($carName,$yearMade, $manufacturer, $batteryAmps) {
        // In a context like this, you can use the parent constructor:
        parent::__construct($carName,$yearMade, $manufacturer);
        $this->batteryAmps = $batteryAmps;  
    }
}
```

Your `Car` class might reasonably extend a `Vehicle` parent class, which would handle all things common to types of vehicles (boats, bikes, etc.). To gloss the logic of OOP class extension and structure/hierarchy (from more abstract to more specific) in a nutshell for you. `(O_o)p`